# SQL Server 2005: How to perform a split on a string

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I have the following string that I need to split from a field called symbols

```
234|23|HC
```

This is my current SQL statement

```
declare @t xml;
Set @t = (
Select symbols from tc for xml auto, elements)

Select @t;
```

which produces `<symbols>234|23|HC</symbols>`

but I need to split the string into child nodes so the result is like this:

```
<symbols>
       <symbol>234</symbol>
       <symbol>23</symbol>
       <symbol>HC</symbol>
</symbols>
```

Comment: Can your symbols contain any characters that would cause issues with a simple replace and append method?

Comment: A simple option; select '<symbols><symbol>'+replace(fld, '|', '</symbol><symbol>')+'</symbol></symbols>'

Comment: @Alex yes but that will produce &lt; etc. which i can't have in the xml file

Comment: @Alex Hey thank you alex, that works great, i cant believe i didnt think of that

Comment: If you create XML you **want** the `&lt;` etc. Not having them is illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A replace version that takes care of the problem characters.

```
declare @T table(symbol varchar(50))
insert into @T values ('234|23|HC|Some problem chars <> &')

select cast('<symbols><symbol>'+
             replace(cast(cast('' as xml).query('sql:column("symbol")') as varchar(max)), 
                     '|', 
                     '</symbol><symbol>')+
             '</symbol></symbols> ' as xml)
from @T
```

Result:

```
<symbols>
  <symbol>234</symbol>
  <symbol>23</symbol>
  <symbol>HC</symbol>
  <symbol>Some problem chars &lt;&gt; &amp;</symbol>
</symbols>
```